# Sightseeing in the Dakotas without a car

Tags: usa, sightseeing, north-dakota, south-dakota

I'm currently a resident of Phoenix, AZ ; I don't have a car and don't plan on buying one either in the near future. I've always wanted to go sightseeing in the Dakotas.

Is it possible to go on tours in the Dakotas without a car? What are my best options?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I may be off my rocker here but why would you need to **buy** a car to drive one?  There are bus tours of South Dakota:

- [Rapid City Tours](http://www.rapidcitytours.com/?event=offer.type&productType=BUS&mpt=599)
- [Other Dakota Bus Tours](http://www.southdakota.com/south-dakota-bus-tours/91)
- [Dakota Trailways](http://www.mydakotatrailways.com/)
- [ND Tourism](http://www.ndtourism.com/grouptravel/)

But I think the simplest option would be to rent a car:

- [Avis](http://www.avis.com)
- [Hertz](http://www.hertz.com)
- [National](https://www.nationalcar.com/index.do?&iataNumber=NC001462&affiliateRes=Y&cm_mmc=Google-_-Brand-_-GS_SE_Rental_B_NTL_E_US-_-national.com)
- [Budget](http://www.budget.com/budgetWeb/home/home.ex)

I mean if you have an indefinite amount of time you can certainly walk the Dakotas.

Comment: I like that last statement

Answer (score 5):

I meet 3 tourists from Switzerland who where on a 6 months bike tour across the states; if that is your kind of thing and you are up for the challenge. Get a (good) used one and it might even be cheaper than a bus tour.

Or you can [catch a lift from Phoenix](http://www.shareyourride.net/carpool/USA/Arizona/Phoenix/) towards Dakota, meet new people and still get around without your own car. However make sure you don't end you trip in a small village without a bus connection if you hitchhike, otherwise you will have a really hard time getting out of there again :)